# Angular- Is it possible to use content projection from within a child component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

NOTE- I realize this example could much more easily be done without using content projection.  I am using it as a very simplified example.

Lets say I have the following component that lists of names in two different elements:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-list',
  templateUrl: `
  <div class='large'>
    <h1>Large Names</h1>
    <ng-content select="large"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class='small'>
    <h1>Small Names</h1>
    <ng-content select="small"></ng-content>
  </div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./name-list.component.css']
})
export class TestNgContentComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

I can then call this component from a template with two lists of names as follows:

```html
<app-names-list>
  <h1 ngProjectAs="large" *ngFor="let n of names">{{ n }}</h1>
  <h2 ngProjectAs="small" *ngFor="let n of names">{{ n }}</h2>
</app-names-list>
```

Notice that the same data is used for both lists of names.  Is it possible to replace the passed h1 and h2 tags, with a component that contains both, and projects them to the parent?  E.g. something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-name',
  template: `
    <h1 ngProjectAs="large">{{name}}</h1>
    <h2 ngProjectAs="small">{{name}}</h2>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

and then modify the template to look like:

```html
<app-names-list>
  <app-name *ngFor="let n of names" [name]="n"></app-name>
</app-names-list>
```

Once I embed the `ngProjectAs` directives in the `app-name` template, this no longer works.  Is there a way to do a projection like this from within a child component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my approach:

I wrapped the `header tags` in an `ng-template` so it can be **attached** to an `ng-container` as an embedded view.
You can read more about `embedded` and `host` views [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-name',
  template: `
    <ng-template #large>
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #small>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    </ng-template>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @ViewChild('large', { static: true, read: TemplateRef }) large: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('small', { static: true, read: TemplateRef }) small: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Here I have replaced `ng-content` with `ng-container` so that I can attach embedded views.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-list',
  template: `
    <div class='large'>
      <h1>Large Names</h1>
      <ng-container #large></ng-container>
    </div>

    <ng-container #foo></ng-container>

    <div class='small'>
      <h1>Small Names</h1>
      <ng-container #small></ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TestNgContentComponent {
  @ContentChildren(HelloComponent, { read: HelloComponent }) children: QueryList<HelloComponent>;
  @ViewChild('large', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) largeNamesContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('small', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) smallNamesContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterContentInit () {
    this.populateView();
  }

  private populateView () {
    this.largeNamesContainer.clear();
    this.smallNamesContainer.clear();

    this.children.forEach(child => {
      this.largeNamesContainer.createEmbeddedView(child.large);
      this.smallNamesContainer.createEmbeddedView(child.small);
    });
  }
}
```

[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-proj-from-within-child?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Good show Andrei Gătej - I was halfway into writing my own response when I saw yours come through.

Comment: Fantastic!  That seems to work great.  Is there any reason this would fall apart if rather than a simple <h1> or <h2>, I am using more complex components, with inputs/outputs?  Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a single component (`app-name` in the example) manage two separate "templates" that appear on the page (in different locations) at the same time (the `h1` and `h2` elements).  I extended my example where the name is actually a new component that takes the name as an input, and it seems to work great.

Comment: Glad it worked! I think you can add pretty much everything you want inside app-name as long as it is wrapped by an ng-template. ng-temaplate does the magic! When you reference a component from the view and read it as ‘TemplateRef’, that variable will effectively hold what’s inside(what’s being wrapped by) that ng-template. With the help of ng-container, you can easily attach these embedded views wherever you want.